# Add meta tag in <head>

Tags: outsystems

I like to add a meta tag in the `<head>` of my html page to prevent zoom on mobile.

But I cannot find a way to do this in OutSystems.
On the forum they refer to the extension [`HTTPRequestHandler`](https://www.outsystems.com/forge/component-details/63/Extension+HTTPRequestHandler/), but this extension is deprecated.

They state

> Starting in version 6.0, this solution is installed with the Platform Server and will no longer be available as a standalone download.

but I cannot find where this should be.

I use OutSystems 9.0.1.50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have this extension published by default in your environment. Have you double checked?

Comment: I think i'm going blind. Have been looking for it for days and could not find it :-(. Checked it one more time after your reply and I find it :-). Time for some cafeine...

Answer (score 1):

HttpRequestHandler is already "inside" the platform. You can find it on Service Studio - http://screencast.com/t/lLohEvkxSv

cheers,
Vera